# showing an alert box from server side to client side in express js, react js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am making a CRUD application, which is working perfectly fine. Now I am trying to show it to the front end that either the user input FirstName already exists or not. Right now I can print the following message using **console.log()**.But I want to show it on the client side, like enabling some div or showing a dialog box which consists the message of 'Username already exists'.

This is my **client side** file:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./AddEdit.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";

import { useState } from "react";

const initialState = {
  FirstName: "",
  LastName: "",
  FatherName: "",
  userCNIC: "",
  Contact: "",
  Gender: "",
};

const AddEdit = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  const { FirstName, LastName, FatherName, userCNIC, Contact, Gender } = state;
  const [gender, setGender] = useState();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { id } = useParams();

  // this useEffect will run when we have the id
  // when we have the id, this basically means we are updating the content.
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/get/${id}`)
      // here we will get the response in the form of array, that will contain only one data.
      // as it is fetching only single row based on the id.
      .then((resp) => setState({ ...resp.data[0] }));
  }, [id]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    var phoneno = /^\d{11,12}$/;
    var cnicno = /^\d{12,13}$/;

    // var console = window.console;
    // var console = global.console;
    // console.log = function (msg) {
    //   if (msg.includes("FirstName already exists!")) myFunc();
    // };

    // function myFunc() {
    //   alert("function invoked");
    // }

    
    // to prevent the default behavior of the browser.
    e.preventDefault();
   

    if (!Contact.match(phoneno)) {
      // checking phone validation
      toast.error("Please provide correct phone number!");
      e.preventDefault();
    } else if (!userCNIC.match(cnicno)) {
      // checking phone validation
      toast.error("Please provide correct CNIC Number!");
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      // if user has no id, it means it is only adding the record.
      if (!id) {
        axios
          .post("http://localhost:5000/api/post", {
            FirstName,
            LastName,
            FatherName,
            userCNIC,
            Contact,
            Gender,
          })
          // once user is successfully able to pass the data to database, then clear the each input field.
          .then(() => {
            setState({
              FirstName: "",
              LastName: "",
              FatherName: "",
              userCNIC: "",
              Contact: "",
              Gender: "",
            });
          })
          .catch((err) => toast.error(err.response.data));
        toast.success("Contact added Successfully");
      } else {
        // else it is updating the record.
        axios
          .put(`http://localhost:5000/api/update/${id}`, {
            FirstName,
            LastName,
            FatherName,
            userCNIC,
            Contact,
            Gender,
          })
          .then(() => {
            setState({
              FirstName: "",
              LastName: "",
              FatherName: "",
              userCNIC: "",
              Contact: "",
              Gender: "",
            });
          })
          .catch((err) => toast.error(err.response.data));
        toast.success("Contact Updated Successfully");
      }
      // when all the data is submitted, navigate to the home page.
      setTimeout(() => navigate("/"), 500);
    }
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setState({ ...state, [name]: value });
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
      <h1>Enter Student Details</h1>

      <Container>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form">
          <Form.Group controlId="form.Name">
            <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter name"
              name="FirstName"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              value={FirstName || ""}
              id="FirstName"
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="form.Name">
            <Form.Label>last name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              id="LastName"
              name="LastName"
              placeholder="Last Name"
              value={LastName || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="form.Name">
            <Form.Label>father name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              id="FatherName"
              name="FatherName"
              placeholder="Fathers name:"
              value={FatherName || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="form.Name">
            <Form.Label>CNIC name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              id="userCNIC"
              name="userCNIC"
              placeholder="CNIC:"
              value={userCNIC || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="form.Name">
            <Form.Label>Contact name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              id="Contact"
              name="Contact"
              placeholder="Contact number"
              value={Contact || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="form.Name">
            <Form.Label>Gender name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              id="Gender"
              name="Gender"
              placeholder="Gender:"
              value={Gender || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <input type="submit" value={id ? "Update" : "Save"} />
          <Link to="/">
            <input type="button" value="Go Back" />
          </Link>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddEdit;
```

And this is the **post method in client side** file in which I am showing an error of 'FirstName already exists'

```
// to add the record in the database.
app.post("/api/post", (req, res) => {
  // values we will pass from the front end and recieve in the req.body.
  const { FirstName, LastName, FatherName, userCNIC, Contact, Gender } =
    req.body;
  const sqlGet = "SELECT id FROM emp_table WHERE FirstName = ?";
  db.query(sqlGet, FirstName, (error, result) => {
    if (result) {
      console.log("FirstName already exists!");
    } else {
      const sqlInsert =
        "INSERT INTO emp_table (FirstName, LastName, FatherName, userCNIC, Contact, Gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
      db.query(
        sqlInsert,
        [FirstName, LastName, FatherName, userCNIC, Contact, Gender],
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            res.send("Values inserted!");
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send error response to the client as i have added in your code below:-

```
app.post("/api/post", (req, res) => {
  // values we will pass from the front end and recieve in the req.body.
  const { FirstName, LastName, FatherName, userCNIC, Contact, Gender } =
    req.body;
  const sqlGet = "SELECT id FROM emp_table WHERE FirstName = ?";
  db.query(sqlGet, FirstName, (error, result) => {
    if (result) {
      console.log("FirstName already exists!");
      return res.status(422).send("FirstName already exists!");
    } else {
      const sqlInsert =
        "INSERT INTO emp_table (FirstName, LastName, FatherName, userCNIC, Contact, Gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
      db.query(
        sqlInsert,
        [FirstName, LastName, FatherName, userCNIC, Contact, Gender],
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            res.send("Values inserted!");
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
});
```